# cron google spreadsheet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron, google-docs, google-sheets

I don't know a lot about Cron Jobs,
but i'm hoping it can resolve an issue with my website.

I've set up an app on Google App Engine (Java)
which, among other things, embeds a published google spreadsheet (html).

But the site takes a long time to load ("loading docs.google.com") when it's been a while since anyone has visited the site.

Can I schedule cron on google app engine to visit my published spreadsheet regularly? (I wouldn't know how, but I'm hoping it's possible). Or is there an other alternative?

Comment: Sound like a bad idea, also make sure it the spreedsheet who takes a long time to load and not the site.

Comment: ... I'm pretty sure polling docs.google.com isn't going to make a difference to loading times. But caching your data locally certainly would.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a cron.xml file that you can deploy to do this. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron